# fix position for uitoolbar (iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone, toolbar, position, uitoolbar

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to set a fix position for a toolbar, for example:

In my UIViewController I got an UITableView and an UIToolbar. If the table view have 50 rows, how can I set the toolbar is always at the bottom of the view, so that I don't have to scroll down first to get to the toolbar. The toolbar should be shown at anytime.

I hope you know what I mean and thanks in advance for your answers.
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a UINavigationController, and 2.x compatibility is not required, you should use the [`toolbarItems` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW51) to create a toolbar attached to the controller.

See also [What's the right way to add a ToolBar to a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072604/whats-the-right-way-to-add-a-toolbar-to-a-uitableview).